# Reuse repository in controllers .NET CORE MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I create the web app include Home Page and Admin Page. I create a `_sliderRepository.AllSliders` to return of list of sliders in a database. How I reuse the repository code for 2 controllers

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    private readonly ISliderRepository _sliderRepository;

    public HomeController( ISliderRepository sliderRepository)
    {
    
        _sliderRepository = sliderRepository;
    }

    public IActionResult Index()
    {  
        return View(_sliderRepository.AllSliders);
    }
}

public class AdminController : Controller
{
    private readonly ISliderRepository _sliderRepository;
    
    public AdminController( ISliderRepository sliderRepository)
    {
        _sliderRepository = sliderRepository;
    }

    public IActionResult Slider()
    {
        return View( _sliderRepository.AllSliders);
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean "how"? It appears you're doing it. What's not working? What's preventing you from accomplishing your goal?

Comment: I want to reuse the code. Because 2 actions do the same thing

Comment: @AdrianIftode and what is the question? he has only `?` in the title ... which is not a question but affirmative sentence  maybe *How I reuse the repository code for 2 controllers* ... but  he is **reusing repository** already in this code

Comment: The two actions **don't** do the same thing. One displays a Home View, the other displays an Admin view

Comment: I mean data they return is the same

Comment: The data is the same, the code isn't. There's no duplication to remove. Besides, by Tuesday you'll realize an Admin page requires different data from a generic Home page and have to add another repository to AdminController. If you used inheritance to remove the field assignment or the `return View()` call, you'd find it really hard to modify AdminController without breaking Home

Answer (score 0):

Several options:

#### Use inheritance

Create a base controller class that inherits the `Controller` class and add there methods like `CreateViewFrom`. The main disadvantage here is if you use some service that needs to be injected in the base controller, then all inheriting controller would have to provide the service.

#### Use extension methods

Just create static class and define there extensions methods that again will create the responses you need. The main disadvantage here is you don't have access to functionality that exists in the *Controller* class.

#### Do nothing

You can do nothing, the cost is zero, just copy and paste code across controllers. The disadvantage is over time the maintenance cost increases. You need to find the best time when to decide to attack code duplication. In my experience do it as soon as possible.

#### General advice

Keep your controllers very light, they should not be *services*. In your particular example I can predict at some point you would want to save a slider in the database and the slider images in storage. Don't do this orchestration in the Controller classes. Extract an `ISildersService` abstraction and do the orchestration there. Keep 'em light.

Comment: Third option: do nothing. They have separate concerns and should be able to vary independently. DRY is about not duplicating business logic - it isn't about minimising code repetition.

Comment: There's no duplication in the question's code. Inheritance would only add problems by having multiple classes inherit ... what? The assignment to a field? The Index method, that may have to change as soon as the OP realizes that an Admin page needs different data from a Home page?